# mysql trigger to sum column where column id equals last inserted row id and store

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a WEBSITE table like so:

```
WEBSITE
web ID | url         | progress
-------------------------------
1      | example.com | 67
```

I have a PROGRESS table like so:

```
PROGRESS
progress id | linking website id | amount to increase
---------------------------------------------------
1           | 1                  | 60
2           | 1                  | 7
```

When a row is inserted into PROGRESS using INSERT INTO,

I use php and mysql to get the accumulative values FROM the PROGRESS table, and then store the new value into the progress value FROM the WEBSITE table.

HOWEVER...

I was wondering if I could use these triggers I've been hearing about to automatically sum up the new progress value and store it?

Is this possible?

Comment: Just a quick note- you've misspelled amount in your table schema, there should only be one _m_ - might make for a nice gotcha for future developers :)

Comment: HAHAA I've always spelt it with 2 m's ... I've never actually realised... cheers:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use a trigger, you can just add the progress to the existing row in `website` but if you wanted to try a trigger you can use the following

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER progress_update AFTER INSERT ON `progress`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE `website` SET `progress` = `progress` + NEW.ammount_to_increase WHERE web_ID = NEW.linking_website_id;
  END;
$$

delimiter ;
```

You can also find further information on the syntax and use of triggers in on the manual page [12.1.11. CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: I realised now that i dont need to use triggers! but thankyou for the example provide:)

Answer (score 2):

You could use triggers, but you don't need to; just do this:

```
update website set 
progress = progress + ?
where web_id = ?
```

And take you values from your query. This is guaranteed to work, because the update is atomic (you don't have to worry about other processes inserting/updating concurrently)